# How to resize the /data F2FS partition

Tags: cyanogenmod, file-system, encryption, partitions, disk-encryption

#### Context:

I wiped all the partitions from my Moto G device with the TWRP recovery and installed Cyanogen 13 on it. Then I had issues when enabling Encryption: the phone just restarts but does not encrypt. This is a known issue and [is described here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117405/how-do-you-encrypt-your-device-running-cyanogenmod-12-1).

I wanted to follow a procedure described in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/131293/57668) (based on [this](https://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/116348-cyanogen-121-encryption-setup-does-not-finish/?do=findComment&comment=546188)), which reportedly works. The explanation is:

> When encrypting the phone, partition /dev/block/mmcblk0pXX -
>   originally containing an ext4 filesystem which is mounted as /data and
>   /sdcard - now contains an encryption container. This will be decrypted
>   early in the boot process and returns a logical partition
>   /dev/block/dm-0 which then holds the ext4 filesystem for /data and
>   /sdcard. (...)
>
> To fix that, the filesystem in /dev/block/mmcblk0pXX needs to be at
>   least 16KiB smaller than the partition itself, which can easily be
>   done by resize2fs.

In short, the proposed solution is to resize the `/data` partition, removing some sectors from it...

> Important is the number of blocks (...) From this number, we subtract 8, which leaves not 16KiB but a safe 32 KiB of space for the encryption header (you don't mind 16KiB on a 12GB volume, seriously)

*The actual number of blocks to be removed from the `/data` partition depends on the **sector size** for the partition. In the example above it's 4KB, so 8x4 =32*.

---

#### The problem

These instructions only apply to the *ext2/3/4* file systems; the necessary commands (*e2fsck, tune2fs, resize2fs*) won't work with the [F2FS partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS) used by Cyanogen v13.

I found `fsck.f2fs` in the */sbin* directory, which I used instead of *e2fsck* and *tune2fs*. Below are the steps from the root ADB Shell, booted to TWRP:

```
~ # mount | grep data

/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem on /firmware type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p36 on /data type f2fs (rw,seclabel,relatime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,active_logs=6)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p36 on /sdcard type f2fs (rw,seclabel,relatime,background_gc=on,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,active_logs=6)
/dev/block/mmcblk0p33 on /cache type ext4 (rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered)

~ # umount /dev/block/mmcblk0p36

~ # fsck.f2fs -f /dev/block/mmcblk0p36

Info: Force to fix corruption
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 11583232 (in 512 bytes)

(...)
```

So, my `/data` partition is `mmcblk0p36`, and is 11 583 232 sectors in size. Each sector is 512 bytes, thus I must shrink the partition to a final size of *11 583 168* sectors in order to leave 32KB unallocated.

**But how can it be done?** Everything seem to indicate that shrinking an F2FS partition is not possible, but I'm not sure. If it is not, and assuming I did a full backup of the `/data` partition, **what are the steps to delete and re-create it with a smaller size?**

Comment: Recreating the *partition* with a smaller size wouldn't solve your issue, if I read the quotes correctly: *To fix that, **the filesystem** in `/dev/block/mmcblk0pXX` needs to be at least 16KiB **smaller than the partition itself*** (emphasis mine). I've no experience with F2FS, but is there a `mkf2fs` or `mkfs.f2fs` command available? You could then run that with the appropriate parameters to re-create the file system with the corresponding size (which of course would destroy all data on the current file system on that partition, so make a backup first).

Comment: @Izzy It worked! Thanks mate. I credited you on [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286395/154671).

Comment: Glad to read! And thanks for posting it as answer with details (upvoted ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today (May 30, 2016), the F2FS file system doesn't support shrinking. *If it does by the time someone reads this, just let me know in the comments.*

The solution is then to **delete and re-create the entire filesystem** for `/data`. From [this related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286395/154671) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange:

```
mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p36 11583168
```

This will do the trick. After rebooting and restoring the backup, and finally, rebooting to Android, the encryption process worked.

**Important:** Be sure to check `Use rm -rf instead of formatting` from the TWRP settings prior to restoring the backup.

Comment: `resize.f2fs 1.12.0` supports shrinking as well as expanding.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I can't find any evidence that shrinking should be supported - where did you read that?

Comment: You can find `f2fs-tools` (including `resize.f2fs`) compiled statically for ARM [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/exe-static-linux-binaries-for-arm-android-cryptsetup-encfs-f2fs-tools-testdisk-photorec.3709380/post-87211203).